# Drupal commerce based recommendations engine

Tags: commerce, rating

I want a shop where experts join the shop and each expert recommends his favorite products.

- Expert's user profile will show his recommended products.
- Users can vote recommendations up and down, much like happens in amazon.
- The product's page will show the recommendations for that product.
- The expert will also be an affiliate.

Possible architecture:

- Commnets may be themed to be recommendations, together with voting stars.
- Affiliates may be added with the [Post Affiliate Pro](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_post_affiliate_pro) integration.

Questions:

- From your experience, what are the best modules / drupal commerce extensions to support this scenario?
- Is there another, internal affiliate solution?

Thanks

Amnon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use comments to be recommendations but I would use nodes. This will give more flexibillity.

Here is a possible architecture:

I would use the [flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag) module to let user flag (recommend) a product.
On flagging, I would use hook_flag to create a new node (content type: recommendation). This node would [reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) to the product. The new node would contain a body field that will contain the actual recommendation. Finally, I would attach the [rate](http://drupal.org/project/rate) module to this node so that users will be able to vote on it.

As far as I know the flag 3.x module is now an entity, which means that you can attach fields to the flag. So, another possible architecture would be to use the flag itself for storing the recommendation. Have not tried this though but seems interesting.